# MySQL Unknown column in 'order clause'

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have one procedure in my MySQL Database.

My procedure working fine. But currently I have to set `order by tblUserKeyStatus.createdDate` inside `IF (opt=1)` condition and when I set order by, It gives me the following error

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'tblUserKeyStatus.createdDate' in 'order clause
```

My Stored Procedure is given below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_GetStatus(IN _userId varchar(64) , IN _qtr int, IN opt int)
BEGIN
    IF (opt = 1) then
        SELECT tblKeyStatus.*,'pending' AS `Status`,'' as scheduleDate,
        ' ' as doneDate,' ' as result FROM tblUserKeyStatus,tblKeyStatus WHERE tblKeyStatus.trimId not in
        (SELECT trimId from tblUserKeyStatus WHERE userId=_userId)
        union
        SELECT tblKeyStatus.*,tblUserKeyStatus.`Status` AS `Status`,tblUserKeyStatus.scheduleDate,
        tblUserKeyStatus.doneDate,tblUserKeyStatus.result FROM tblKeyStatus,tblUserKeyStatus WHERE 
        tblUserKeyStatus.trimId=tblKeyStatus.trimId and tblUserKeyStatus.userId=_userId
        order by tblUserKeyStatus.createdDate;
    Else
        SELECT * from tblKeyStatus WHERE qtr=_qtr;
    End if;
END
```

Comment: Is there such a column?

Comment: @juergend Yes `createdDate` is the column of `tblUserKeyStatus` Table with `Datetime` type.

Comment: after union put the select statement in braces

Comment: try out the query which I posted as answer

Comment: The `ORDER BY` refers to the result of the `UNION`. First error: in the union result there is no longer a table `tblUserKeyStatus`, but just a set of rows. Second error: You haven't even selected a column named createdDate, so it's not in your result set and hence you cannot sort by it.

Comment: By the way: you are using the comma-separated join syntax that was made redundant 25 years ago with SQL-92. Is your query that old or how come? Use explicit ANSI joins instead. The first join is a cross join. Is this on purpose? I don't think so. Why do you even join with tblUserKeyStatus; you are not using any of ist columns. Also use alias names for the tables, so as to get your query more readable. And why are you using `UNION` and not `UNION ALL`? Are there duplicates to remove? (Other than the half-purposely created ones with the first query I mean.)

Comment: Is trimId unique for tblKeyStatus? And trimId + userId unique for tblUserKeyStatus?

Answer (score 1):

Try having braces for select

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE proc_GetStatus(IN _userId varchar(64) , IN _qtr int, IN opt int)
    BEGIN
        IF (opt = 1) then
            SELECT tblKeyStatus.*,'pending' AS `Status`,'' as scheduleDate,
            ' ' as doneDate,' ' as result FROM tblUserKeyStatus,tblKeyStatus WHERE tblKeyStatus.trimId not in
            ((SELECT trimId from tblUserKeyStatus WHERE userId=_userId)
            union
            (SELECT tblKeyStatus.*,tblUserKeyStatus.`Status` AS `Status`,tblUserKeyStatus.scheduleDate,
            tblUserKeyStatus.doneDate,tblUserKeyStatus.result FROM tblKeyStatus,tblUserKeyStatus WHERE 
            tblUserKeyStatus.trimId=tblKeyStatus.trimId and tblUserKeyStatus.userId=_userId
            order by createdDate));
        Else
            SELECT * from tblKeyStatus WHERE qtr=_qtr;
        End if;
    END
```

Comment: Giving syntax error at the end of the line `((SELECT trimId from tblUserKeyStatus WHERE userId=_userId)`

Answer (score 1):

`ORDER BY` is applied to the whole query specified in the `UNION` operation, so that the entire result set returned by `UNION` is ordered.

Try to select `createdDate` field in *both* subqueries, so that it is accessible to `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT tblUserKeyStatus.createdDate,
       tblKeyStatus.*,'pending' AS `Status`,
       '' as scheduleDate,
       ' ' as doneDate,
       ' ' as result 
FROM tblUserKeyStatus, tblKeyStatus 
WHERE tblKeyStatus.trimId not in (SELECT trimId 
                                  from tblUserKeyStatus 
                                  WHERE userId=_userId)
UNION

SELECT tblUserKeyStatus.createdDate,
       tblKeyStatus.*,
       tblUserKeyStatus.`Status` AS `Status`,
       tblUserKeyStatus.scheduleDate,
       tblUserKeyStatus.doneDate,tblUserKeyStatus.result 
FROM tblKeyStatus,tblUserKeyStatus 
WHERE tblUserKeyStatus.trimId=tblKeyStatus.trimId and 
      tblUserKeyStatus.userId=_userId
ORDER BY createdDate;
```

You also have to remove the `tblUserKeyStatus` name prefix.

Comment: I don't want to get `tblUserKeyStatus.createdDate` as column. I just want to get result order by `tblUserKeyStatus.createdDate`.

Comment: @user3441151 Wrap the whole query in  subquery and select in the outer query any fields you wish.